# java Bean list = new Bean(resultset.getString(1),resultset.getString(2),resultset.getString(1)+resultset.getString(2))

Tags: servlets

Bean list = new Bean(resultset.getString(1),resultset.getString(2),resultset.getString(1)+resultset.getString(2))

Doing as above I can't get the results I want. Is there any way to sum those two values?

Any answers are appreciated.

```
while(resultSet.next()){
            if (i < sum.size()) {
                Bean l = sum.get(i);
                String a = l.getSum();
                String b = resultSet.getString(2);
                int ab = Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b);
            RetBean list = new RetBean(resultSet.getString(1),
                    resultSet.getString(2),l.getSum(),ab);
```

here my error
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "728.57"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at pms.Test.doGet(Test.java:57)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Wow. Great question. What is the results you want? What do you get now? Where is your code?

Comment: i want to sum those two values as i sum from database but when i sum like above the result is for example getString(1)=19.2  getSring(2)=4.5  then getString(1)+getString(2)=19.24.5

Comment: You are doing string concatenation with the `+`. You need to convert to a Number type first.

Comment: while(resultSet.next()){
    if (i < sum.size()) {
     Bean l = sum.get(i);
     String a = l.getSum();
     String b = resultSet.getString(2);
     int ab = Integer.parseInt(a)+Integer.parseInt(b);
          ReportBean list = new ReportBean(resultSet.getString(1),
      resultSet.getString(2),l.getSum(),ab);

Comment: please help me check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of guessing here, but if you want to sum up two integers contained in Strings you could do

```
 int sum = Integer.parseInt(firstString) + Integer.parseInt(secondString);
```

For decimal numbers, you could do

```
 BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.valueOf(firstString)
    .add(BigDecimal.valueOf(secondString));
```

If you have numbers in the database, you should not use `getString`, there are `getInt`, `getDouble`, `getBigDecimal` as well.